# Prevent EntityFramework from setting foreign keys to null

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am using EF6 with a soft-delete implementation, so I don't want EF to either cascade-delete or set foreign keys to null. We need to keep a record of the relationship in the database.

I was able to prevent EF6 from creating cascade-delete foreign keys by removing the model builder conventions like this:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

However, EF6 still sets the foreign keys to null. 
Here is a tiny example:

```
public class BaseEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DeletedOn { get; set; }
}
public class Project : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
public class Task : BaseEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ProjectId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ProjectId")]
    public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

When I load a project and its related tasks from the database, then delete the project, the ProjectIds of the tasks are set to null.

```
using (var context = new TestModelContext())
{
    var project = context.Projects.FirstOrDefault(c => c.DeletedOn.HasValue == false);
    var tasks = project.Tasks.ToList();
    context.Projects.Remove(project);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I already got the source code of EF6 and found that in line 2579 of the EntityEntry Delete function, it seems to be hard-coded that EF nulls all foreign keys. When I remove the three lines (2579-2581), it works. But is this really what everyone needs? Is there a way to configure this behavior?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How/where is implemented your soft delete? And when is it used?

Comment: @Guillaume We're using EF Dynamic Filters for soft delete. It is applied globally and can be turned of in rare cases. https://github.com/zzzprojects/EntityFramework.DynamicFilters

Comment: I'm not talking about querying but deleting, it looks like you are hard deleting entities and not soft deleting

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue? I am having the exact same problem